# Python docstrings are unexpectedly None

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.4, docstring

When I create a class with method like this:

```py
class Foo:
    """ A class """
    def bar():
        " Hello world "
        pass
```

I would expect the `__doc__` to return the first statement of the method, since both are strings. Unfortunately, this does not happen:

```py
print(Foo.__doc__)
print(Foo().__doc__)
print(Foo.bar.__doc__)
print(Foo().bar.__doc__)
```

outputs `None` 4 times. Also the example here

[https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functools.html?highlight=**doc**#functools.wraps](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functools.html?highlight=__doc__#functools.wraps)

seems to fail, as the docstring is `None` for me:

```py
from functools import wraps
def my_decorator(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwds):
        print('Calling decorated function')
        return f(*args, **kwds)
    return wrapper

@my_decorator
def example():
    """Docstring"""
    print('Called example function')
print(example.__doc__)
```

Which also prints `None`.

Why are the `__doc__`'s not set to the specified strings?

ideone snipplet: http://ideone.com/cZNUQe

Comment: Wow: on my local machine these all output the expected docstrings (`sys.version == '3.4.3+ (default, Oct 14 2015, 16:03:50) \n[GCC 5.2.1 20151010]'`)

Comment: Works on my machine, it might be a bug with ideone.

Comment: Also: I saw the same behavior of `__doc__` being `None` on my machine for less minimal examples (== customer production code).

Comment: Well, without those examples, I don't know how we can help.

Comment: @MorganThrapp Obviously, my point is that I would need some time to get a better MWE.

Comment: My problem is decorator-related though. However, the ideone-behavior above still is weird.

Answer (score 3):

**Update:** Based on [@user2357112's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37551518/python-docstrings-are-unexpectedly-none#comment62592200_37551689), I found a way to reproduce ideone's behavior in a local interpreter, and it's likely the cause for the weird discrepancies. Specifically, it looks like ideone is running a wrapper script in Python *without* the `-OO` flag, but using [the `compile` builtin function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#compile) to compile the user provided code with `optimize=2` as the argument, then `eval`ing the resulting compiled code object. It looks like this causes the the split behavior previously mentioned; `sys.flags.optimize` is `0`, and `__debug__` is `True` (matching the state of the outer interpreter), but docstrings and `assert` statements are stripped (matching the optimization level used when `compile` is called).

To reproduce, run the following script with Python without passing the `-OO` flag:

```
source = '''import sys
print(sys.flags)
print("Debug:", __debug__)
if __debug__:
    print("Debug")
else:
    print("Non-debug")
class Foo:
    """abc"""
print("Foo docstring:", Foo.__doc__)
assert True == False
'''

compiled = compile(source, '<test>', 'exec', optimize=2)
eval(compiled)
```

The output is:

```
sys.flags(debug=0, inspect=0, interactive=0, optimize=0, dont_write_bytecode=0, no_user_site=0, no_site=0, ignore_environment=0, verbose=0, bytes_warning=0, quiet=0, hash_randomization=1, isolated=0)
Debug: True
Non-debug
Foo docstring: None
```

where the first two lines behave as if running without `-OO`, while the next two lines (and the absence of an `AssertionError`) behave as if `-OO` is in effect. It looks like `sys.flags` checks are performed at runtime (which means they reflect the main interpreter state), `__debug__` is half and half (`if` checks and possibly other conditional logic is performed at compile time, while other usage is runtime, note how `__debug__` `print`s as `True`, but tests as `False`), while stripping docstrings and `assert`s is finished entirely during compilation (so they reflect the state of `compile`'s `optimize` flag).

---

**Old answer that applies more often outside ideone**:

For non-ideone cases, behavior like this would indicate you're running with the `-OO` switch (double optimized). When run with [`-OO`, docstrings are stripped during byte code compilation, replaced with `None`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-OO); setting `PYTHONOPTIMIZE` environment variable to `2` would have the same effect.

Comment: But the `optimize` flag is set to 0 http://ideone.com/Zq9TdR

Comment: @vaultah: On the other hand, if you deliberately feed Ideone a syntax error, the [traceback](http://ideone.com/BD67QR) you get is coming from the `py_compile` module rather than a regular Python syntax error. It seems to be performing separate compilation and execution steps. `py_compile` [defaults](https://docs.python.org/3/library/py_compile.html) to compiling code at the same optimization level as the current interpreter.

Comment: I suspect that the Ideone guys set Python to run at `-OO` for the compilation pass without realizing that the compiled code would inherit that `-OO` setting, even when `-OO` is not specified for the execution pass.

Comment: @vaultah: On further checks, agreed, something is fishy. It's halfway acting like `-OO` is set, and halfway like neither `-O` nor `-OO` is set; `assert`s and docstrings are stripped per `-OO`, but `sys.flags` and the special `__debug__` variable are acting like not even `-O` was set. I'm guessing ideone is using some custom Python implementation that doesn't quite match the expected, documented behavior, because it should not be possible for `assert`s to be skipped while `__debug__` is `True`, those are mutually exclusive, and both controlled by `-O` alone.

Comment: @user2357112: I can't reproduce with `py_compile` (which writes out optimization level specific bytecode files), but I can get similar behavior with the `compile` built-in function. I'm investigating for complete repro in local Python.

Comment: @user2357112: I managed to reproduce the exact behavior using the `compile` built-in with explicit `optimize=2` while the interpreter calling `compile` was run without optimization. Looks like `assert` and docstrings are fully stripped during compilation, while `sys.flags` and, surprisingly, `__debug__`, are left in place and looked up at runtime. Confusingly, a statement like `if __debug__:` is resolved at compile time (verified by performing `dis.dis` of code that includes `if __debug__: print("Debug")`, `else: print("Non-debug")`), so `__debug__` is _partially_ compile time specialized.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: `py_compile` normally writes to an optimization level-specific output location, but if you specify a `cfile` argument, it'll write output there, even if the extension and optimization level don't match.

Comment: Regarding `-OO` or `-O`, are these python or gcc/g++ flags?

Comment: @Herbert: Python. See the link in my answer, or run `python --help`.