# Writing docstring for custom PySide6 class

Tags: python, pyside6

I am subclassing `PySide6.QtCore.QObject` and writing class docstring. However, `__doc__` is returning `None` instead of my docstring.

```py
>>> from PySide6.QtCore import QObject
>>> class MyObj(QObject):
...     """My docstring."""
>>> MyObj.__doc__ is None
True
```

Is this a bug, or do I need to use some other way to document my class? I am currently using `PySide6==6.3.0`.

Comment: Maybe related? https://stackoverflow.com/q/50471942/ https://stackoverflow.com/q/37551518

Comment: It is a bug that I already reported: https://bugreports.qt.io/projects/PYSIDE/issues/PYSIDE-1884